# what are factors which are responsible for changing pid_max

Tags: process, linux-kernel, configuration

I have checked two linux systems, both were of 64 bit but PID_MAX is different for both of them.

On one system

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
```

Whereas on other, it was

```
 cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max 65536
```

From proc man pages.

> proc/sys/kernel/pid_max This file (new in Linux 2.5) specifies the
>   value at which PIDs wrap around (i.e., the value in this file is one
>   greater than the maximum PID). The default value for this file, 32768,
>   results in the same range of PIDs as on earlier kernels. On 32-bit
>   platfroms, 32768 is the maximum value for pid_max. On 64-bit systems,
>   pid_max can be set to any value up to 2^22 (PID_MAX_LIMIT,
>   approximately 4 million).

Please note, both of these system were having same linux kernel.

Now, my question is what are factors which are responsible for changing pid_max? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the default value is calculated from the max potential number of CPUs(rhel).

Run this command on each of the systems

```
dmesg | grep -i smp.*allow
```

Alternatively it's possible that the limit was changed by an admin previously?

Comment: on first system, this command gives me blank output whereas on second it says, "SMP: Allowing 64 CPUs, 61 hotplug CPUs". How does that maked difference, please explain.

Comment: pid_max = min(pid_max_max, max_t(int, pid_max,
                PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT * num_possible_cpus()));

Comment: PIDS_PER_CPU = 1024. The default value will be 32768 or num_possible_cpus(64)*1024 which ever is higher.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are accessing a docker or open VZ container and not a real linux machine ? In such a case, the host can limit PID_MAX to any value. This is a relatively new feature, and it is called Cgroup pid controller. It is a kind of anti fork bomb solution, which prevents the container from endlessly forking processes, which will make the host unusable in a very short time.